# Storing a reference within class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to keep a reference to a pointer of a different class in my class. I'm trying to see if there is a way to do this without having to define it in the ctor. I cannot make a copy, as I'm using that specific pointer returned to do other things.

```
class MyClass {
private:
    OtherClassPtr &m_ptr_ref;

public:
    MyClass();

public:
    void MyFunction() {
      m_ptr_ref = otherClassPtr->GetPtrRef();
      if(!m_ptr_ref)
        return;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is `otherClassPtr->GetPtrRef()` declared static?

Comment: No. It returns a pointer via reference, non-statically.

Comment: I didn't ask about the return value. Is the function a static function or not?  Perhaps you should us the declaration for `GetPtrRef()`.  If not, is the object pointed to by otherClassPtr a static or const object?

Comment: Is your goal simply to hide the dependency of `MyClass` on whatever type `otherClassPtr` is pointing to?

Comment: otherClassPtr is an extern global pointer. That's irrelevant though. My goal is to be able to have a member variable which is a reference to a pointer. I cannot do this since It forces me to initialize it with a lvalue reference ( which I cannot obtain from  otherClassPtr->GetPtrRef() at the time the ctor is run )

Comment: Is that `otherClassPtr` statically initialized?

Comment: No it is not. /2short

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Include the declaration and definition of `OtherClassPtr`.

Answer (score 1):

A reference needs to be initialized at the point of declaration, and cannot change to refer to a different object during its lifetime. Thus you need to set it in the constructor.

An alternative is to store a pointer. I think of a reference as a pointer with nicer syntax, though the different syntax gives it a different semantic meaning; it acts like the object that it refers to, and so has the same value and the same address as that object. Most relevant to your question, the assignment operator works like assignment to the object, rather than a pointer. This is the reason it cannot change referent.

You can keep a pointer to the pointer:

```
OtherClassPtr* m_ptr_ref;
/* ... */
m_ptr_ref = &otherClassPtr->GetPtrRef();
```

An alternative is to use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), but that is nothing more than a fancy pointer, and I don't see the advantage over using a pointer.

Comment: Wrt the implementation this could be correct (although it is not required). But from the language a reference is semantically not a pointer. The most obvious difference is one has a value the other not (more precisely: the value of a reference is the value of the referenced object).

Comment: That would require me to change the return type of the other function to a pointer. I cannot do that. It is a static library. It returns a pointer via reference.

Comment: @Olaf : you make a good point. I've edited the answer, I hope you can agree with it more now. :)

Comment: @BruceHansworth: You can return `*ptr` if you need to return a reference to the object pointed to.

Comment: I dont think that I can do this. `OtherClassPtr = OtherClass*` it is returned by reference in GetPtrRef. If i have a pointer to a pointer, I cannot access functions from within that OtherClass

Comment: *"A reference needs to be defined at the point of declaration"* you mean initialized

Comment: Doh!  This is why you are supposed to post an [MCVE] and it is foolish for the rest of us to try and help until you have done so.

Comment: @BruceHansworth: I don't see where the problem could be, you can dereference pointers and obtain a pointer to a variable (or reference). Update your question to show the full problem.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, you can actually eliminate an entire level of indirection, since `typedef OtherClass *OtherClassPtr;` is probably the case here.  Just change m_ptr_ref to m_ptr and take the address from the ref returned by GetPtrRef()

Comment: @jwdonahue: That is what I suggested, I think. But I honestly don't know what OP is up to, it's likely that the whole question would go away with a better design.